C strcat buffer overflow after hundreds of iterations
I have written a status bar utility in C for DWM to display the time, date, CPU temp, and battery level. I recently noticed the program had crashed and found that it had a coredump. I recompiled the utility to include debugging symbols to debug with gdb and it crashed about 10 minutes after starting. While analyzing the coredump with coredumpctl debug I found the following line in the backtrace.
0x0000716af522c799 in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=msg@entry=0x716af52ba153 "buffer overflow detected") at fortify_fail.c:24

I have been combing through the code but I dont understand what is causing the buffer overflow as it runs fine for extended periods of time and have not had another crash happen sense.
The line in the code causing the issue is:
strcat(status, battery_buff); 

GitHub repository with the code.
Github issue I created.
System Info:

OS: Arch Linux (6.10.5-arch1-1)
Window Manager: DWM (6.4.r5-3)
X11: libx11 (1.8.10-1)
CC: GCC (14.2.1+r32+geccf707e5ce-1)

Full GDB backtrace (thread apply all backtrace full)
Thread 1 (Thread 0x716af50ce2c0 (LWP 1963)):
#0  __pthread_kill_implementation (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=signo@entry=6, no_tid=no_tid@entry=0) at pthread_kill.c:44
        tid = <optimized out>
        ret = 0
        pd = <optimized out>
        old_mask = {__val = {23}}
        ret = <optimized out>
#1  0x0000716af519d463 in __pthread_kill_internal (threadid=<optimized out>, signo=6) at pthread_kill.c:78
No locals.
#2  0x0000716af5144120 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
        ret = <optimized out>
#3  0x0000716af512b4c3 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
        save_stage = 1
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x20, sa_sigaction = 0x20}, sa_mask = {__val = {6786648855210017280, 0, 140721397189936, 101591911342992, 101591911411072, 100, 32, 140721397190128, 124704192526143, 101591911343744, 101591911343751, 101591911343752, 0, 140720308486146, 124704193122162, 1088703904}}, sa_flags = 907723264, sa_restorer = 0xb}
#4  0x0000716af512c354 in __libc_message_impl (fmt=fmt@entry=0x716af52ba16c "*** %s ***: terminated\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:132
        ap = {{gp_offset = 16, fp_offset = 23653, overflow_arg_area = 0x7ffc40e44ec0, reg_save_area = 0x7ffc40e44e50}}
        fd = 2
        iov = {{iov_base = 0x716af52ba16c, iov_len = 4}, {iov_base = 0x716af52ba153, iov_len = 24}, {iov_base = 0x716af52ba172, iov_len = 17}, {iov_base = 0x3000000030, iov_len = 140721397190376}, {iov_base = 0x7ffc40e44e20, iov_len = 6786648855210017280}, {iov_base = 0x7ffc40e44e60, iov_len = 124704192628220}, {iov_base = 0x5c65b5c98010, iov_len = 528}}
        iovcnt = <optimized out>
        total = <optimized out>
        cp = <optimized out>
#5  0x0000716af522c799 in __GI___fortify_fail (msg=msg@entry=0x716af52ba153 "buffer overflow detected") at fortify_fail.c:24
No locals.
#6  0x0000716af522c124 in __GI___chk_fail () at chk_fail.c:28
No locals.
#7  0x0000716af522db1a in __strcat_chk (dest=dest@entry=0x5c65b5c9a390 " 12:17:25 PM | 08/18/2024 | 100°C | 100% ", src=src@entry=0x5c65b5c9a680 "| 100% ", destlen=<optimized out>, destlen@entry=42) at strcat_chk.c:34
        s1 = <optimized out>
        s2 = <optimized out>
        c = <optimized out>
#8  0x00005c658482c381 in strcat (__dest=0x5c65b5c9a390 " 12:17:25 PM | 08/18/2024 | 100°C | 100% ", __src=0x5c65b5c9a680 "| 100% ") at /usr/include/bits/string_fortified.h:140
No locals.
#9  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/dmenustatus/dmenustatus/src/dmenustatus.c:87
        step = 1
        status = 0x5c65b5c9a390 " 12:17:25 PM | 08/18/2024 | 100°C | 100% "
        datetime_buff = 0x5c65b5c9a9a0 " 12:17:25 PM | 08/18/2024 "
        cputemp_buff = 0x5c65b5c9a450 "| 100°C "
        battery_buff = 0x5c65b5c9a680 "| 100% "


Please post a [mre] here that demonstrates the problem. We're not going to read your entire github repo looking for the bug.

Are you sure all the concatenated values fit in 42 bytes, including the null terminator?

Do you really need to allocate status using malloc()?

Add some code just before strcat() to test whether it will overflow, if that's the known point of failure. But the bug could be anywhere, it could be something else that overflows. They don't always have a direct effect.

... and the string that causes the overflow, follow it back. The content may provide clues, as well as by how much it would overflow.

As @Barmar said, 42 bytes is not enough. You're either missing the null terminator, or the fact that ° is an UTF8 character that needs 2 bytes.

to avoid buffer overflow, replace your strcat with something along: if (strlen(status) + strlen(APPENDME) < sizeof(status)) { strcat(status, APPENDME);}  (ensure that the APPENDME is also null terminated)

@ticktalk ...sizeof(status)  Careful here - OP is doing a lot of malloc()'ing of buffers.  sizeof() would be wrong in that case.

@AndrewHenle, ouch , noted, tks, I've just read the code in dmenustatus.c, lots of room for improvement there


Your code is exceedingly inefficient -- you malloc and free lots and lots of buffers, where passing in a single fixed buffer would suffice.

In this code:


char battery_status(char *base)
{
  char status;
  char *buff = readfile(base, "status");

  if (buff == NULL) {
    return 'E';
  }
  if (!strncmp(buff, "Discharging", 11)) {
...
  } else {
    buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
    status = '?';
  }

the buff == NULL is bogus (readfile never returns NULL) and there is a buffer underflow in the else case: if buff is empty, you are writing to buff[-1].

In general, allocating just 42 bytes for status is both buggy and wasteful (malloc probably rounds it up to 48 or 64 bytes anyway).
You'll be much better off restructuring this so you have e.g. char status[512]; and pass a pointer into that buffer into all your subroutines which can append their part and return a pointer past their output. Something along the lines of:
char status[513];
const int sz = sizeof(status) - 1;
while (running) {
  char *p = datetime(status, sz /*sz characters remaining*/);
  p = cputemp(9, p, sz - (p - status) /* remaining space*/);
  p = battery(0, p, sz - (p - status) /* remaining space*/);
...


Tip: To cope with unexpected large temperatures, sprintf with %g rather than %f.
It will move to exponential notation when the values are very large/small and keep the needed buffer size reasonable.

Re "completely unnecessary" -- that code isn't null-terminating the string, it's replacing the last character (presumably a newline) with a null terminator. That's the reason for - 1.
